# Set Server response header in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, http-headers

Is it possible in IIS7, without using URL Scan to remove the Server in the response header?  I have tried the following:

[HttpModule](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/03/12/iis-7-how-to-send-a-custom-server-http-header.aspx)

I've installed a signed one into the GAC and also tried the App_Code directory and neither has worked.  I've also tried setting the

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader
```

registry entry to 1 and still nothing.

EDIT:  I've also tried this: [Community ISAPI filter](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1332)

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Your question appears to be a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/24885/how-to-remove-iis-asp-net-response-headers which should solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove IIS/ASP.NET Response Headers](http://serverfault.com/questions/24885/how-to-remove-iis-asp-net-response-headers)

Comment: When I asked this (18 months ago), that question did not have any IIS7 answers to it that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried adding the following to my application-level "Web.Config" file with varying degrees of success:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="ETag" />
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
        <remove name="X-AspNetMvc-Version" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

This only applies to content served out of the application directory (and subdirectories) and doesn't work when applied to the "applicationHost.config" file underneath the "System32/inetsrv/config" directory.  I've also had this change not work at all (how I came across your question here while researching this issue), so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Doesn't remove the Server header